# Visual Studio 2019 Error BC30311 Value of type 'VehicleMake' cannot be converted to 'VehicleContext'

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

I have project with VB and Entity Framework. I am stuck here. Can someone help me? I don't know how to fix this. I am following tutorial but tutorial use .cshtml and I use .vbhtml.

I am stuck here for 2 hours and can't find solution. Microsoft online help is useless, can't find anything that is good and helps me.

Thanks for your help.

Mono is name of my project

VehicleModel.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Namespace Vehicle.Models
    Public Class VehicleModel
        <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property MakeId As Integer
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Abrv As String
        Public Overridable Property VehicleMake As ICollection(Of VehicleMake)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

VehicleInitilizer.vb

```
Imports Mono.Vehicle.Models

Namespace Vehicle.DAL
    Public Class VehicleInitializer
        Inherits Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of VehicleContext)

        Protected Overrides Sub Seed(ByVal context As VehicleContext)
            Dim VehicleMake = New List(Of VehicleMake) From {
                New VehicleMake With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .Name = "BMW",
                    .Abrv = "BMW"
                },
                 New VehicleMake With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .Name = "Ford",
                    .Abrv = "Ford"
                },
                 New VehicleMake With {
                    .Id = 3,
                    .Name = "Volkswagen",
                    .Abrv = "VW"
                },
                 New VehicleMake With {
                    .Id = 4,
                    .Name = "Hyundai",
                    .Abrv = "Hyundai"
                },
                 New VehicleMake With {
                    .Id = 5,
                    .Name = "Mercedes-Benz",
                    .Abrv = "Mercedes"
                }
        }

            vehicleMake.ForEach(Sub(s) context.VehicleMake.Add(s))
            context.SaveChanges()
            Dim VehicleModel = New List(Of VehicleModel) From {
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .MakeId = 1,
                    .Name = "128",
                    .Abrv = "BMW"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .MakeId = 1,
                    .Name = "325",
                    .Abrv = "BMW"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 3,
                    .MakeId = 1,
                    .Name = "X5",
                    .Abrv = "BMW"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .MakeId = 2,
                    .Name = "Mondeo",
                    .Abrv = "Ford"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .MakeId = 2,
                    .Name = "Focus",
                    .Abrv = "Ford"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 3,
                    .MakeId = 2,
                    .Name = "Fiesta",
                    .Abrv = "Ford"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .MakeId = 3,
                    .Name = "Golf",
                    .Abrv = "VW"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .MakeId = 3,
                    .Name = "Passat",
                    .Abrv = "VW"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 3,
                    .MakeId = 3,
                    .Name = "Arteon",
                    .Abrv = "VW"
                },
                New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .MakeId = 4,
                    .Name = "i30",
                    .Abrv = "Hyundai"
                },
                 New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .MakeId = 4,
                    .Name = "Tuscon",
                    .Abrv = "Hyundai"
                },
                  New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 3,
                    .MakeId = 4,
                    .Name = "Kona",
                    .Abrv = "Hyundai"
                },
                  New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .MakeId = 5,
                    .Name = "C-Class",
                    .Abrv = "Mercedes"
                },
                    New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .MakeId = 5,
                    .Name = "E-Class",
                    .Abrv = "Mercedes"
                },
                    New VehicleModel With {
                    .Id = 3,
                    .MakeId = 5,
                    .Name = "A-Class",
                    .Abrv = "Mercedes"
                }
                }

            VehicleMake.ForEach(Sub(s) context.VehicleModel.Add(s))
            context.SaveChanges()

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

VehicleContext.vb

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions

Namespace Vehicle.DAL
    Public Class VehicleContext
        Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("VehicleContext")
        End Sub

        Public Property VehicleMake As DbSet(Of VehicleContext)
        Public Property VehicleModel As DbSet(Of VehicleContext)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

VehicleMake.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace Vehicle.Models
    Public Class VehicleMake
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Abrv As String
        Public Overridable Property VehicleModel As ICollection(Of VehicleModel)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: In VehicleInitilizer.vb on this line:  

vehicleMake.ForEach(Sub(s)context.VehicleMake.Add(s))

and this line:

VehicleMake.ForEach(Sub(s) context.VehicleModel.Add(s))

Answer (score 0):

At first glance you seem to have a number of problems in your code.

Here:

`Dim VehicleMake = New List(Of VehicleMake) From { ...` you are creating a list with the same name as your class `VehicleMake`. that's very confusing, i suggest naming it something else (`VehiclesMakes` for instance).

But anyway, later on  when you access the list here : `vehicleMake.ForEach(Sub(s)context.VehicleMake.Add(s))` You are accessing the a Property named `VehicleMake` in your class `VehicleContext`. Again, you are accessing a property in a class, and that property is named identically to a class you have created. but your property `VehicleMake` is not actually an object of the `Class` VehicleMake, this is all very confusing.

The `Add` Method of your **Property** `VehicleMake` expects an argument of type `VehicleContext` (because it is defined as `Public Property VehicleMake As DbSet(Of VehicleContext)`). But instead, you give it an instance of you **Class** `VehicleMake`, from your **List** that's also named `VehicleMake`.

You get the error because `VehicleMake` is given where  `VehicleContext` is expected. and `VehicleMake` does not inherited from `VehicleContext`. Thus, it cannot be converted to it.